# I Can not get Readability API parser to work

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, readability

I am trying to use the Readability API parser -
The readability [blog post for python](http://blog.readability.com/2013/06/readability-python-0-2-0/) gives this code example:

```
from readability import ParserClient
parser_client = ParserClient('your_parser_token')
parser_response =          parser_client.get_article_content('http://www.blog.readability.com/2013/06/reada bility-python-0-2-0/')
print(parser_response.content['content'])
```

I of course have put in my personal token number where it say 'your parser_token'.

The error I get is:

ValueError: Required argument 'READABILITY_PARSER_TOKEN' not supplied and not found in environment variables

Does this mean I must have the parser token in my os envirment or is their a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've already solved this problem, but this could be useful for people who might encounter this problem in the future.

According to the documentation (http://readability-python-library.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parser.html), if you are passing the token directly to the `ParserClient` constructor, you will need to put `token=` before the actual token, like so:

`parser_client = ParserClient(token='[the_token]')`

Hope this helps!